# $P(A\cup B) \subseteq P(A) \cup P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please tell me if this solution is correct? Thank you!

$P(A\cup B) \subseteq P(A) \vee P(B)$

Take $x \in P(A \cup B)$

Then $x \subseteq (A \cup B)$

So $x \subseteq A \vee x \subseteq B$

$x \in P(A) \vee P(B)$, so the statement is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Layla16 what does $P$ mean in your question ?

Comment: To Thành Nguyễn: perhaps it is power set...

Comment: Sorry, yes it is the power set.

Comment: Let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3,4\}$ and $x=\{2,3\}$. Then $x\subset (A\cup B)$ but it is a subset of neither $A$ nor $B$.

Comment: $x \subseteq A\cup B$ does not imply that $x \subseteq A$ or $x \subseteq B$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Why would  not be a subset of either A or B? Wouldn't for example  containing 2 be enough to make it a subset of A,  containing 3 be enough to make it a subset of B?

Comment: @Layla16 All elements of $x$ have to be members of $A$ to make it a subset of $A$.

Comment: @Layla16 "Take x ∈ P(AUB)

Then x ⊆ (AUB)

So x ⊆ (A) ∨ x ⊆ (B)" is not true. There should be "Take x ∈ P(AUB)

Then $x \in (AUB)$

So $x \in (A) ∨ x \in (B)$"

Comment: Sometimes, when trying to prove a statement, it really pays to be skeptical and to test it out on some simple examples. If you find a counterexample, then you have proved that the statement is false; in which case you really ought to stop trying to prove that the statement is true. Did you try this on some simple examples of $A$, $B$ and $x \subseteq A \cup B$?

Comment: @LeeMosher In her case, that wouldn't have worked because she thought that only one member of a set had to be included in another for it to be a subset.

Comment: "*Wouldn't $x$ containing 2 be enough to make it a subset of $A$*"  It sounds perhaps like you misunderstand the meaning of the phrase "*is a subset of*" and are conflating it to mean that their intersection is non-empty... that it contains at least one element in common.  That is incorrect.  $\{2,3\}$ is not a subset of $\{1,2\}$.  Yes... $2$ happens to be in both the first and the second, but that is irrelevant here... what your attention should be drawn to is that $3$ is *not* an element of $\{1,2\}$ and so $\{2,3\}$ has at least one element who is not in $\{1,2\}$ and thus is not a subset.

Answer (score 0):

The correct inclusion is the following; given your attempt, you should be able to prove it:
$$P(A)\cup P(B)\subseteq P(A\cup B).$$